# How do i send the data of a form (retrieved from a function of an HTML page) to a function of another HTML page in Django/Python?

Tags: python, django

The sequence is:
- The user fills the 'a' form in the 'A' HTML page.(URL: AppName/A)
- The user is directed to 'B' HTML page with other forms to fill.(URL: AppName/A/B)

In the python code,
How do i send the data of the 'a' form (retrieved from the function corresponding to the 'A' HTML page) to the function corresponding to the 'B' HTML page in views.py ?

Notes:
I do not want to retrieve the data from the 'A' HTML page in the 'B'HTML page but in the function corresponding to the 'B' HTML page as the user goes from 'A' to 'B' HTML page.

Thank you.

Comment: What you want  to achieve using this approach?

Comment: the 'a' form = contract1: yes or no contract2= yes or no. then you submit this form and go to the next page where depending on the contract you selected different forms will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions or database to store form states (form data) for user.

**Sessions**

[How to use sessions in Django official Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/)
[Django Sessions by mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions)

**Database**

Models according to your forms to store form data and also maintain form no which form is filled or not.

**Render both forms**

Render both form in same template and do what you want.

Comment: For the first option it might be too complicated but i will investigate. For the second option my forms already inherit from models so i can have access to the last value  inserted by the user (if yes how can i make it?) For the third option:Render both forms on the same page will not be visually good.